# Отправка POST запроса с пользователем

Tags: php, post, curl, redirect

Ситуация:

1. Пользователь заполняет на *site.com/form* форму к примеру ФИО
2. После нажатия кнопки submit, его перенаправляет на *site.com/processing*
3. *site.com/processing* должен обработать и добавить поле *token* и отправить POST запрос вместе с пользователем нa *anothersite.com/form*

Вопрос как выполнить 3 пункт?

Comment: используйте curl, например

Comment: Буду благодарен если покажите мне пример кода